# Automate ImportHTML to get twitter followers for many cells

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, formulas

I have a spreadsheet with a cell range of twitter profile urls. I want to automate getting their follower count. This is what I came up with.

```
   function getFollowers1() {
      var queryString = Math.random();

      var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); 
      var cellRange = sheet.getRange("L6:L25").getValues();  
      var startCell = sheet.getRange("K6");

      for (var i = 0; i < cellRange.length; i++) {

          var value = '=substitute(query(IMPORTHTML("' + cellRange[i] + '?' + queryString + '",' +'"table", 3), "select Col3"), char(10)&"Followers","")';
          startCell.setValue(value);
          startCell = startCell.offset(1,0);
      }

      var range = sheet.getRange("K6:K25");
      range.copyTo(range, {contentsOnly: true});

    }
```

I have 4 separate functions `getFollowers1, getFollowers2, getFollowers3, getFollowers4` the difference between them is the range of cells. I have about 80 cells and doing it all in one function would always have some cells hang at `Loading...`. I have these 4 functions set to triggers at different times of the day. However, sometimes the function works and sometimes all cells in the function just hang at `Loading...`.

I don't know the reason for this, throttling maybe? I'm wondering how to change things to accomplish what I want in a more efficient and reliable way. To get daily updates of twitter followers.

Comment: If your method calls are similar, I would suggest [using batch operations](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/best-practices#use_batch_operations). "You can write scripts to take maximum advantage of the built-in caching, by minimizing the number of reads and writes. Alternating read and write commands is slow. To speed up a script, read all data into an array with one command, perform any operations on the data in the array, and write the data out with one command." Also included in the link are several ways to optimize your scripting.

Comment: Any idea what is causing some cells to hang at `Loading...`? Would there be any throttling going on either with google sheets or with twitter?